# Why did everyone in The Pit have to jump to their freedom?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

Everyone who tried to escape from The Pit had to jump to the platform in the end.

Why didn't they cover the distance with some wide thick plank instead?

Comment: The wide, thick plank store was closed?

Comment: Somehow I don't believe prisoners didn't have ANYTHING light enough to climb with it to the jumping platform and strong enough to hold a person. In a hundred years they could've torn out jail bars, lift them to the platform and bend them there to get a durable support. Couple of dozens of attempts would've surely got some prisoners out, and voila.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A small child could leap further than a grown adult‽ The jump was a silly plot device about regaining belief in yourself.

If you want to ignore this, then the jump was a way of taunting the prisoners, offering freedom if only you were brave enough.

Prisoners being resourceful types, I think they would quickly jury-rig a solution and all escape.

Comment: Equally impressive as the child making the jump was the man who was recently cured from a broken back by being punched in said broken back also making the jump.

Comment: Even more impressive is your use of the oft-overlooked interrobang! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang

Answer (score 14):

The Pit was a prison.  The point of the Pit was to make escape difficult, otherwise it wouldn't be an effective prison.  The psychological reality of having to jump a great distance in order to escape was likely an even further deterrent than the climb, thus ensuring the Pit's effectiveness *as a prison.*  Basically, you have to earn your freedom. Only people who were highly motivated to escape, and thus to overcome their own fear and physical limitations, would be able to get out, to say nothing of the fact that whoever runs the prison is not likely to facilitate *the escape of dangerous criminals* by installing a wooden plank.

Also, they were in a desert.  Undoubtedly, wooden planks are in short supply.